# Advanced Jira Query Filtering

Tags: filter, jira, jql

How do I include "all issues" from ONE project for a select group of assignees AND also include bugs from other projects for those same assignees in a Jira Query?

Answer (score 7):

There you go:

```
(project = "my project" OR issuetype="Bug") and assignee in membersOf("my user goup")
```